# TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import hashlib
from sys import exit

def md5():
hash1=input("Dame el codigo MD5 : ")
Identificador=1
with open ("diccionarios/rockyou.txt") as f:
    abrir=f.readline().strip()
    for contraseña in abrir :
        md5archivo=hashlib.md5(contraseña.split()).hexdigest()
        print("Comprobando contraseña %s : %s" % (Identificador ,contraseña.split()))
        Identificador+=1
        if md5archivo == hash1:
            print("La contraseña es" ,  contraseña)
    else:
        print("No se encontro la password")
md5()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "md5cracker.py", line 17, in
>   
>       md5()   File "md5cracker.py", line 10, in md5
>       md5archivo=hashlib.md5(contraseña.split()).hexdigest() TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

El codigo en cuanto a espacios , esta desordenado . Alguien sabe alguna solucion a esto ?¿

Answer (score 0):

```
    for contraseña in abrir :
    md5archivo=hashlib.md5(contraseña.split()).hexdigest()
    print("Comprobando contraseña %s : %s" % (Identificador ,contraseña.split()))
```

Cambiando por strip dio otro error :
     TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: Es decir split por strip

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion quitar split y añadir encode